Snowflake clustering -- should inserts be ordered?
Long story short. When you cluster a snowflake table it physically orders it.
Additional inserts are not 'organized/ clustered' into the table, unless you specify to re-cluster/ auto-recluster.
However, with 'naturally ordered tables' --- aka let's say you're clustering by a real-time event timestamp .... if you "order by" in the insert data, the table (provided nothing unusual happens) will never need to be re-clustered, ever.
Therefore, this is a best practice, to "order by" the inserts by the ETL job. Is this correct thinking?

If a table is clustered then Snowflake will automatically re-cluster the table as DML statements are executed against it: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys#reclustering

If 2% of the table is changed, is the re-clustering every update, worth it, cost wise? Does it only do a small amount of work or rescan the whole table? .... I'm thinking ... if a table has 10 years of data .. and 1 day is added (0.01%) ... let's get real. If that daily data is already sorted, no clustering needed. If it's jumbled, it's still all on the same partition for any date based scans. Seems reclustering often is unncessary unless you have a jumbled mess.

A table is either clustered or it isn’t - you can’t have a partially clustered table (which would make no sense, even if it was possible). Whether the benefits of clustering outweigh the costs is something only you can judge for your specific circumstances - as the documentation makes clear

Not sure what you mean. Every snowflake table has micro-partitions and clusters. Whether you "organize it by a key" -- is up to you. You can turn on/ off "RE-clustering" at will. .... If a table is organized A-Z, like a perfect library, and this meta-data is known in the micro-partitions -- you don't need to "recluster". Unless you add a ton more records.

With Snowflake, clustering has a very specific meaning. To quote the documentation “A table with a clustering key defined is considered to be clustered.” - so if you don’t define a clustering key on a table then it is not considered to be clustered. So you can’t turn on/off re-clustering at will - you can add a clustering key to a table, after which Snowflake will automatically ensure that the table is kept clustered with respect to that key, or you can remove a clustering key from a clustered table, after which Snowflake will stop clustering that table with respect to that key

You can suspend recluster on a table with a 'clustering key' -- but to my original post, if a table is ordered correctly "by chance" or by just by the way the insert/ ETL works --- snowflake still 'knows' with some micro-partition meta-data and can take full advantage. .... Seems if you have a jumbled table - you only need to 'recluster' ONCE - then if its naturally ordered by default with additional data, no further reclustering is ever needed. No one has claimed otherwise far as I can tell

Snowflake will only recluster non-constant partitions. That said, I don't know if partitions previously determined as "non-constant" are revisited after every insert, which if true, would get more expensive over time. If your ETL is insert only, with occasional "partition-pruning friendly" deletes, pre-sorted inserts are worth exploring

If you insert in a natural order, AND the clustering is good enough that your most critical queries do not have too much partion read waste. You do not need to order on insert. By definition.
If you have an natural order, but insert a weeks worth of data at a time, for examples, and do lots of day bases filter, that natural order of the 7 days of data, might not be so flast. The esay thing to do is make a second table as an order version of the data, and check important queries. If this was a good performance gain you might want to use clsutering to reorder things. In this case if your key column is a timestamp it might be worth using a order grain of day date_as_timestamp::date as the cluster key, because if you are doing day based filtering, sub-day order has no meaning.
Then the last point to note, (up to the present date 2024) UPDATE's can destroy order of the clustered partitions that are rewriten, and it only takes a single row in the partition to rewrite all rows (this is how partition's work), but the write partitions are a "random mix" of ALL ROWS. So if you change 2% of rows, that come from 30% of your paratitions, those partitions most likely will be random.
Clustering will slow re-write this, but if you are doing insert DDL every couple of minutes, it might take hours for the reclustering. And the cost of the recluster if it get interurpted, can cost 20X the cost to rewrite the whole table.
And Snowflake know about this since clustering was added, and they have had plans to fix it, but the performance cost (to the customers that do not want large table updates to be ordered (which the DML does not allow for) blocks some of the value of clustering.
Aka it can work, but it also can not work sometimes, and you should test, watch and monitor.

Mmm. Well. I hear you with the updating. ... I suppose the best thing to do is test real-world applications. .... Essentially testing the cost of writes + one-off clusters (maybe occasional reclusters) ... vs the savings in read time. ...... An effective ordering or clustering technique might actually save money in some cases ... and then weigh that against performance improvements.
